# Add custom validation in Flutter using Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, validation, firebase-authentication

I have made a login page using Flutter which asks for '**Application Number** (which are just numbers)', '**Password**' & '**DOB**' as shown below.

[image: Contains Application Number, Password & DOB]

I have already added validations to it like it shouldn't be empty & only numbers & atleast one capital etc. But I also want to add custom validation using Firebase to **Application Number** & **Password** where only certain Application Numbers and their corresponding passwords will be allowed to enter which are specified in the database.
I have already added Firebase to my Flutter app.

Here is the code of the login page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  DateTime date = DateTime(2005, 06, 13);
  TextEditingController dateinput = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //key for form
  String name = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateinput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFffffff),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              key: formKey, //key for form
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: height * 0.04),
                  Text(
                    "LEARNERS",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Color(0xFF363f93)),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "LICENSE TEST",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Color(0xFF363f93)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.05,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration:
                        InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter Application Number"),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty ||
                          !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                        return "This cannot be empty / \nThis can only contain numbers";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.05,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter Password"),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty ||
                          !RegExp(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$')
                              .hasMatch(value)) {
                        return "Minimum eight characters, \nat least one uppercase letter, \none lowercase letter and one number";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.05,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      controller:
                          dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                          iconColor: Colors.white, //icon of text field
                          labelText: "Enter Date Of Birth" //label text of field
                          ),
                      readOnly: true,

                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return "Please select the Date of Birth";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      }, //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
                      onTap: () async {
                        DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                            context: context,
                            initialDate: date,
                            firstDate: DateTime(
                                1900), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                            lastDate: DateTime(2006, 06, 13));

                        if (pickedDate != null) {
                          print(
                              pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                          String formattedDate =
                              DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);

                          print(
                              formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                          //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

                          setState(() {
                            dateinput.text =
                                formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
                          });
                        } else {
                          print("Date is not selected");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.08,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff4c505b),
                        child: IconButton(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => TestScreen()),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward,
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: `Application Number & Password where only certain Application Numbers and their corresponding passwords will be allowed to enter which are specified in the database` 

From this seems like you will be querying firebase, I'd approach this by adding a field say `canLogin:true`, if false display a message.

Comment: do add  how you are trying to verify the data